# Transaction Failed: Error: 1014: Priority is too low: (515000139 vs 515000139)

Tags: substrate

I play with https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template and I want to make transaction like:

[image]

But I got:

```
 Transaction Failed: Error: 1014: Priority is too low: (515000139 vs 515000139): The transaction has too low priority to replace another transaction already in the pool.
```

Any idea?

I ask those questions because I want to archive my on-boarding to Substrate and then make introduction video with all those ob-boarding issues to make life easier developers in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error implies that there is already a transaction in the transaction queue with the same nonce. This means that you need to wait until the next block to submit your tx, or write some custom logic which handles incrementing the nonce and submitting multiple transactions in the same block.

If you want to replace the tx in the transaction queue, you should submit the new transaction with a `tip` to increase the priority, and also resolve this issue. But only one transaction with a certain nonce can be valid, so this transaction with a `tip` will replace the old transaction.

Comment: Do you know how to make a transaction with a tip by Polkadotjs lib?

Comment: I am also looking to see how I can create a transaction with a tip using the polkadot.js library